# Adding keywords to documet library to enable better search

Tags: enterprise-keywords, keyword

Apart from adding Enterprise keywords. Is there any other way just o add keywords to a document library.So when you upload a document as an item yo can tag it?
Will this then improve search?

Answer (score 0):

I usually add a query rule for items that I want to appear when specific search terms are entered.  Maybe that will help?

See this:

https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/mspfe/2013/02/01/how-to-customize-sharepoint-2013-search-results-using-query-rules-and-result-sources/